# Como organizar versões de projeto no GitHub?

Tags: laravel, git, github

Tenho um projeto antigo que foi escrito em **Laravel 5.3**, recentemente reescrevi todo o código utilizando a versão **5.5**.

Minha dúvida está em como organizar isso no Github, atualmente, o branch master comporta meu projeto baseado em Laravel 5.3, localmente tenho o projeto reescrito na versão 5.5

Como solução pensei em migrar a versão 5.3 para outro branch e subir a 5.5 para o master, porém, não sei se é assim que funciona. Caso este seja o caminho, como posso executar estes passos?

Comment: Sim. Esse é o caminho. Mova o código com a versão 5.3 para outro `branch`. Para isso use o comando: `git checkout -b 5.3` e depois `git checkout master` para retornar para o `branch` principal. Aí você já pode substituir com os novos arquivos. `Faça o backup de tudo antes.`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr depois dessa ação ai bastaria um push?

Comment: Exato. Depois é só executar `git push origin master` para atualizar `branch` principal ou `git push origin 5.3` para atualizar o `branch` anterior.

Comment: Compreendi essa parte, entretanto tenho a seguinte dúvida: atualmente tenho em 1 diretório a versão 5.3 e em outro a versão 5.5, eu continuo trabalhando em diretórios separados ou após este push eu deveria mover o conteúdo de 5.5 > o diretório onde está o 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sempre utilizo `branches` para isso.

Para utiliza-lo também, use o comando: `git checkout -b 5.3` e depois `git checkout master` para retornar para o `branch` principal.

Eu também sempre opto por deixar tudo na mesma pasta. Não há problemas quanto a isso *(exceto se você errar algum comando, por exemplo, `git push origin branch_errado`)*.

Quando você usar o comando `git checkout master`, os arquivos que estão no `branch 5.3` não serão visíveis e nem modificáveis. E quando utilizar o `git checkout 5.3` os arquivos que estão no `branch master` não serão visíveis e nem modificáveis.

**Criando branch 5.3 e criando um arquivo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alterando e visualizando os arquivos do branch master**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você execute o comando `git diff master 5.3`, ele lhe mostrará todas as diferenças.

```
diff --git a/Agora estou no branch 5.3.txt b/Agora estou no branch 5.3.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

> Faça o backup de tudo antes.

Comment: Após realizar essa operação ai posso voltar a trabalhar no master e depois aplicar a alteração de ambos os branch com git push de uma só vez?

Comment: Sim. Você pode.